# activemq dependency does not work well with logback

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, activemq-classic, slf4j

At the moment when I run my program , I get the following in my console:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.1/logback-classic-1.1.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/.m2/repository/org/apache/activemq/activemq-all/5.9.0/activemq-all-5.9.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
```

As stated in the issue [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-5009) "there is no way for us to use maven dependency exclusions command to not take the activemq-all contributed slf4j-log4j12 artifact."
I'm not sure I follow the work around for it for now. Does it mean I have to use 5.10-SNAPSHOT? I was going to settle for activemq-core like the answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20828922/play-framework-2-1-x-test-conflict-with-slf4j-api), but I need stuff that are released in 5.9.0 and the core only goes up to 5.9. I hope someone can give me suggestions please. I really need help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, if activemq-all does not fit your needs, start with the activemq-client jar instead.

The old activemq-broker jar was cut into several pieces some versions back.

You might want the JMS specs included as well:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
    <artifactId>geronimo-jms_1.1_spec</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I tried to use activemq-client but it doesn't include the stuff that I need and thats using it to make a stomp client. It cannot resolve imports like: `import org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.Stomp;`

Comment: Use this as well:
`<dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
 <artifactId>activemq-stomp</artifactId>
 <version>5.8.0</version>
</dependency>`

ActiveMQ has the dependencies divided into smaller chunks so that you don't get a bloated application if you only need certain parts.

Comment: Oh wow I need a slap in the face lol. I replaced **activemq-all** with **activemq-stomp** as really thats the only thing I need for activemq and it now works perfectly. Thank you for your help Petter, you're the best :)